# Sending mail with android application

Tags: android, email, gmail

I'm writing an android application that suppose to send an e-mail in some point. I created a new e-mail account in google. The user name is: pickup.friend.carpool. This is my mail sending class:

```
public class MailSending {

    private static String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private static String USER = "pickup.friend.carpool@gmail.com";
    private static String PASSWORD = ""; //My password
    private static String PORT = "465";
    private static String FROM = "mail.com";
    private static String TO;
    private static String STARTTLS = "true";
    private static String AUTH = "true";
    private static String DEBUG = "true";
    private static String SOCKET_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    private static String SUBJECT;
    private static String TEXT;

    public void send(String to) {
        TO = to;
        SUBJECT = "subject";
        TEXT = "body of mail";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", USER);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", AUTH);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", STARTTLS);
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", DEBUG);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SOCKET_FACTORY);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        try {

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setText(TEXT);
            message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
            message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
            message.saveChanges();

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);

            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call this class on my other activities:

```
(new MailSending()).send("e-mail receiver");
```

Every time the program enters the mail sending class it falls on the line where this is written: message.saveChanges();
On my AndroidMainfest file I have only permission for internet.
Maybe I have permission problems with my AndroidMainfest file? What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hello other than the permission for the internet,
Why don't you try adding the following permissions as well?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I hope it works..